# exporting the webpage content to pdf and excel format

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mysql-workbench

In my application i have a webpage created for the user, which display the content from the mysql workbench in the tabular format. this application is created using spring mvc(eclipse ide). in this page i have created a export button, on click of this button the contents present the table will be exported to pdf or excel format and the generated file should be downloaded to the download folder.

Can anyone help with:

1. extract these table content
2. export the content to pdf/excel(xls)
3. download of the file on click of the button.

I am totally confused how do i start with it. any reference for how to read the webpage content and proceed with this will be helpful.

Comment: You already have that data on your controller before you send it to the view. Create a file from it and add your button pointing to it.

Comment: sorry i had missed one part in my question--- "application is getting the data in json format from the kafka, which is processed by .js file and it sends the received data to the respective html page".

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure of what you want to do, but to extract a website content is easy with `Jsoup`, it is a great `html` parsing library and can be downloaded [here](http://jsoup.org/). To produce `excel` file you could use a library developed by Apache - [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). A tutorial on how to do this can be found [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you can do-

Since you are displaying the contents in a webpage, you already have an API that fetches the data from the data source. You can utilize the same API for getting the data. You would then need to turn that data into a CSV format. On top of this you can have a little REST service that serves contents of type text/csv. Your download button in the UI can invoke this REST to get the CSV file downloaded. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry i had missed one part in my question--- "application is getting the data in json format from the kafka, which is processed by .js file and it sends the received data to the respective html page". so it does even include the  concept of converting the json object.

Comment: In that case think you can have a json to csv converter (on the server side). Just like your .js file consumes json, you REST could convert it to CSV and send as response to client.

Comment: yes, that could be tried but what if i give another feature like checking the few fields which the user wants to export. i mean the user can select or deselect the fields which he want to export. the fields would be the table fields

Comment: That should be straight. In that case I think you get the list of columns to be exported from the UI, so your JSON to CSV converter can exclude the columns you don't want. Something like Utils.jsonTocsv(json, listOfColumnsToConvert) be your interface.